# Simple regex doesn't work

Tags: c#, regex

I want to match the strings "F1" to "F12". I only need the number. I'm out of training - my first try:

```
var r = new Regex(@"^(?:[F])[\d]{1,2}$");
```

matches - but returns "F1" - but i expect to get "1"?

What have I done wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "returns"? You're not calling anything! Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. (I suspect the problem is that you need to define a capturing group for the part that you want, and then extract the value for that group.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you are using a non-capturing group for the "F", the overall match for your `Regex` will return the entire string it matched.  Groups are used to outline sub-expressions within your regular expression that you want be able to extract the value of.  Non-capturing groups are used if you want to specify a sub-expression without having it be stored in a group.  They allow you to apply quantifiers to your sub-expression, but do not allow you to extract their resulting value after running the regex against a string.  They are typically used for performance gains, since capturing groups add extra overhead.

If you want to get just the number, you need to put the number portion in a capturing group and look at the [Groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of the resulting [Match](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (assuming you are calling the `r.Match` function).

The updated `Regex` would be:

```
var r = new Regex(@"^(?:[F])([\d]{1,2})$");
```

Since our number is inside of the first set of parenthesis associated with a capturing group, it will be group 1.  You could also name your group to avoid confusion or possible errors if the regex gets updated at a later date.

Alternately, you can just use look-behind as M42 has suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you want to use lookbehind:

```
var r = new Regex(@"^(?<=F)\d\d?$");
```

Comment: Sorry - couldnt get it work :-( Calling r.Match("F1") should work? No Group[X].Value contains a result